# Possible to have google AR core and Unity WebCamTexture running simultaneously?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arcore

I was wondering if it's possible to have both, a Google ARCore Device camera and a a Unity native WebCamTexture running the same image.

The reason for this is that i need images that have more detail, however the ARCore device is rather blurry because of it's fixed focus point.

Right now I'm creating a WebcamTexture and have the TextureReader to access the ARCore. However it the WebcamTexture only works a split second before the TextureReader kicks in.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, currently it is not possible.
The mobile device camera can only be accessed by one application at a time.